# Memmove in same pointer for deleting multiple whitespaces C

Tags: c, pointers, removing-whitespace, memmove

while this Code works:

```
 char * k = "asd"; 
 char * j = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
 memmove(j,k,3);
 printf("%s",j);
```

while code gives error:

```
 char * k = "asd";
 char * j = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
 memmove(k,k+1,3);
 printf("%s",k); // output should be "sd"
```

I am thinking wrong? Why it gives an erorr? I'm planning to use it for deleting the multiple whitespaces ("aaa.......bbb"(dots are spaces) -> "aaa bbb")

Thank you.

Comment: The above code is bogus and works just by luck. You are not copying the trailing `\0`. So the string j has no terminating `\0`. In the second code you are modifying the global constant "asd" which is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A declaration like

```
char *k = "asd";
```

causes the string literal to be stored in the read-only data segment. (C compilers tend to not warn for this case even though declaring the pointer as `const char *k = "asd"` would be safer, for historical reasons.)

If you want the string contents to be modifiable, you will need to use an array instead, like

```
char k[] = "asd";
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
memmove(k,k+1,3);
```

tries to shift the elements of string literal `asd` by `1`. String literals are non modifiable. Any attempt to modify it will invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `char *k = "asd"`, the string `"asd"` is placed in the read only parts of memory and the pointer k is made to point there. You cannot write to this location using `memmove()`.

You should instead use `char k[] = "asd"`.